# Is there a way to update with new data a Radial (or Circular) bar chart after rendering?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'd like to display a Radial (or Circular) bar Highchart chart https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/radial-bar-chart

Since the data takes longer to be calculated, I'd like to display the graph then update the data when ready.

As the default plot the graph with no values but then update after some time-consuming calculations. I've tried as below to no futile.

I tried using radialGraph.series.update(); function but gets an error Uncaught TypeError: radialGraph.series.update is not a function.

Does anyone know how to go about it? Thank you.

```js
// Loads default values

radialGraph = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    colors: ['#FFD700', '#C0C0C0', '#CD7F32'],
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        inverted: true,
        polar: true
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Winter Olympic medals per existing country (TOP 5)'
    },
    tooltip: {
        outside: true
    },
    pane: {
        size: '85%',
        innerSize: '20%',
        endAngle: 270
    },
    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            useHTML: true,
            allowOverlap: true,
            step: 1,
            y: 3,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px'
            }
        },
        lineWidth: 0,
        categories: [
            'Norway <span class="f16"><span id="flag" class="flag no">' +
            '</span></span>',
            'United States <span class="f16"><span id="flag" class="flag us">' +
            '</span></span>',
            'Germany <span class="f16"><span id="flag" class="flag de">'  +
            '</span></span>'
        ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        crosshair: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#333'
        },
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickInterval: 25,
        reversedStacks: false,
        endOnTick: true,
        showLastLabel: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0.15
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Gold medals',
        data: [0, 0, 0]
    }, {
        name: 'Silver medals',
        data: [0, 0, 0]
    }, {
        name: 'Bronze medals',
        data: [0, 0, 0]
    }]
});



// After some time-consuming computations, update the series data with the below sample.

    radialGraph.series.update([{
        name: 'Gold medals',
        data: [132, 105, 92]
    }, {
        name: 'Silver medals',
        data: [125, 110, 86]
    }, {
        name: 'Bronze medals',
        data: [111, 90, 60]
    }]);
    
    // I tried updating as above but keep getting: Uncaught TypeError: radialGraph.series.update is not a function
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.com/downloads/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/flags16.css" />

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `series` property is an array. To update it you can use `chart.update` method:

```
    radialGraph.update({
        series: [{
            name: 'Gold medals',
            data: [132, 105, 92]
        }, {
            name: 'Silver medals',
            data: [125, 110, 86]
        }, {
            name: 'Bronze medals',
            data: [111, 90, 60]
        }]
    });
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/09um5nr8/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

---

Or change data for each series by `series.setData` or `series.update` method:

```
    const series = radialGraph.series;
    
    series[0].setData([132, 105, 92], false);
    series[1].setData([125, 110, 86], false);
    series[2].setData([111, 90, 60]);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xws8a5co/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData